# Is there a better way to do this in JavaScript? Array search using while

Tags: javascript

I'm thinking of ways to improve the following piece of code, mostly by minimizing the lines of code, but also keeping it clear to the reader what the code does. Could I somehow use `indexOf()` in the example below?

```
var events = myArray.data.items;

data = null;
found = false;
counter = 0;
if (selectedValue != "") {
    while (!found && counter < events.length) {
        //notice there's an extra layer of objects for each object in the array
        if (events[counter].data.Event_ID == selectedValue) { 
            data = events.items[counter].data;
            //do stuff
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions about improving working code are a better fit for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

You can do a trick using the [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
var data = null;
var found = events.some(function (event) {
    return event.data.Event_ID == selectedValue ? ((data = event.data), true) : false;
});
```